# Cannot see properties of NuGet library project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, nuget, project-template

In `Visual Studio 2015`, if I create a project with the template `"Class Library (Package)"`, when I right click on the project and select `Properties`, I see this error in the properties windows:

> An error occurred trying to load the project properties window.  Close the window and try again.
>
> COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used.

Any idea on how to fix this (before I try re-installing...)?

Answer (score 0):

This problem was caused by GhostDoc version 4.9, and has been fixed in version 5.